# We need to know the domain so we can white list it

Tags: buildfire

The developer of our plugin needs to know the source and destination of the login call so that they can white list the domains.  How can we get this information?

Comment: In case you don't know what a domain is, it is the URL of the login service.

Comment: If this is a BuildFire question, can you be more specific ? is the developer using BuildFire UI for login, SSO or OAuth2 ?